# JOIN EACH and GROUP EACH BY clauses can't be used on the output of window functions

Tags: google-bigquery

How would you overcome the above restriction?

I am trying to find flows based on sequences of 3 records using the LEAD and LAG window functions, and than calculate some aggregations (count, sum, etc,) of their attributes.

When i run my queries on a small sample of data, everything is fine and the group by runs OK. but when running on larger data set, i get: "Resources exceeded during query execution. The query contained a GROUP BY operator, consider using GROUP EACH BY instead."

In many other cases switching to GROUP EACH BY do the work...
However, as I use window functions, I cannot use EACH...

Any suggestions? Best practices?

here is a sample query based of wikipedia sample data. it shows the frequency of title editing by different contributors. the where condition is just to limit response size, if you remove the "B" we get results, if we add it we got the "use EACH" recomendation.

```
select title,count (case when contributor_id<>LeadContributor then 1 else null end) as different,
count (case when contributor_id=LeadContributor then 1 else null end) as same,
count(*) as total
from
(
SELECT title,contributor_id,lead(contributor_id)over(partition by title order by timestamp) as LeadContributor  
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
where regexp_match(title,r'^[A,B]')=true)
group by title
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset? Sample queries?

Comment: Can you please provide your user? i will grant you read permissions to my production environment and share my problematic query.

Comment: Hi user2881671; I'd prefer to first give it a shot with publicly discussable queries and/or data. For 24x7 one-on-one support Google offers premium support packages, while StackOverflow strives to be a community based channel. There's a lot of people that could help and learn from this issue, if you are willing to share more.

Comment: added a sample query based on wikipedia public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your particular use case is different to the sample query, but let me comment on what I'm able to see:

- You found a way to make GROUP EACH and OVER possible: Surrounding the OVER() query with another one allows you to change the GROUP BY to GROUP EACH BY. However, this query's problem is not there.
- Let's forget about GROUP and GROUP EACH. Let's look at the core query:

  ```
  SELECT title, contributor_id, LEAD(contributor_id)
      OVER(PARTITION BY title ORDER BY timestamp) AS LeadContributor
  FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
  WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(title, r'^[A,B]')
  ```
- This query fails with r'^[A,B]' and works with r'^[A]', and it highlight an OVER() limitation: As GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it only works when data fits in one machine, as they are not parallelizable. As the answer to r'^[A]' reveals, that can be a lot of data - though sometimes not enough. That's why BigQuery offers the parallelizable GROUP EACH BY. However, there is no parallelizable OVER EACH BY we can use here.
- The workaround I would apply here is exactly what you are doing: Do the OVER() with just a fraction of the data.

(btw, let me say I love the sample query... it's an interesting question with an interesting answer!)

Comment: As you guessed, my particular case is different. Unfortunately Querying in chunks is too complicated for me... I have rewrote my query without window functions, but with some heavy Joins and aggregations (Min, Max)... the code is not as elegant as i wish it was, but it works :)