# Parallelizable OVER EACH BY

Tags: google-bigquery

I am hitting this obstacle again and again...

[JOIN EACH and GROUP EACH BY clauses can't be used on the output of window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966816/join-each-and-group-each-by-clauses-cant-be-used-on-the-output-of-window-functi)

Is there a best practice or recommendations how to use window functions (Over()) with very large data sets that cannot be processed on a single node?

Fragmenting my data and running the same query with different filters can work, but its very limiting, takes lot of time (and manual labor) and costly (running same query on the same data set 30 times instead of once).

Referring to Jeremy's answer bellow...
It's better, but still doesn't work properly. 
If I take my original query sample:

```
select title,count (case when contributor_id<>LeadContributor then 1 else null end) as different,
count (case when contributor_id=LeadContributor then 1 else null end) as same,
count(*) as total
from
(
SELECT title,contributor_id,lead(contributor_id)over(partition by title order by timestamp) as LeadContributor  
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
where regexp_match(title,r'^[A,B]')=true
)
group by title
```

Now works...
But

```
select title,count (case when contributor_id<>LeadContributor then 1 else null end) as different,
count (case when contributor_id=LeadContributor then 1 else null end) as same,
count(*) as total
from
(
SELECT title,contributor_id,lead(contributor_id)over(partition by title order by timestamp) as LeadContributor  
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
where regexp_match(title,r'^[A-Z]')=true
)
group each by title
```

Gives again the Resources Exceeded Error...

Answer (score 1):

Window functions can now be executed in distributed fashion according to the PARTITION BY clause given inside OVER. If you supply a PARTITION BY with your window functions, your data will be processed in parallel similar to how JOIN EACH and GROUP EACH BY are processed.

In addition, you can use PARTITION BY on the output of JOIN EACH or GROUP EACH BY without serializing execution. Using the same keys for PARTITION BY as for JOIN EACH or GROUP EACH BY is particularly efficient, because the data will not need to be reshuffled between join/aggregation and window function execution.

Comment: I am still getting Resources exceeded during query execution. job ID: playscape-proj:job_AMuawphXDbY91iOdbZne3cDdK1o. I know that my "Partition By" groups are not of balanced size, so it can explain it... but this is my data. any idea?

Comment: Edited the Original question with a sample that still does not work :(

Comment: See discussion on bug: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=100

Answer (score 0):

Update: note Jeremy's comment with good news.

OVER() functions always need to run on the whole dataset as the last step of execution (they even run after the LIMIT clauses). Everything needs to fit in the last VM, unless it's parallelizable with a PARTITION clause.

When I find this type of errors, I try to filter as much data as I can in earlier steps.

For example, this query doesn't run:

```
SELECT Year, Actor1Name, Actor2Name, c FROM (
 SELECT Actor1Name, Actor2Name, Year, COUNT(*) c, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY c DESC) rank
 FROM 
 (SELECT Actor1Name, Actor2Name,  Year FROM [gdelt-bq:full.events] WHERE Actor1Name < Actor2Name),
 (SELECT Actor2Name Actor1Name, Actor1Name Actor2Name, Year FROM [gdelt-bq:full.events] WHERE Actor1Name > Actor2Name),
 WHERE Actor1Name IS NOT null
 AND Actor2Name IS NOT null
 GROUP EACH BY 1, 2, 3
)
WHERE rank=1
ORDER BY Year
```

But I can fix it easily with an earlier filter, in this case adding a "HAVING c > 100":

```
SELECT Year, Actor1Name, Actor2Name, c FROM (
 SELECT Actor1Name, Actor2Name, Year, COUNT(*) c, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY c DESC) rank
 FROM 
 (SELECT Actor1Name, Actor2Name,  Year FROM [gdelt-bq:full.events] WHERE Actor1Name < Actor2Name),
 (SELECT Actor2Name Actor1Name, Actor1Name Actor2Name, Year FROM [gdelt-bq:full.events] WHERE Actor1Name > Actor2Name),
 WHERE Actor1Name IS NOT null
 AND Actor2Name IS NOT null
 GROUP EACH BY 1, 2, 3
 HAVING c > 100
)
WHERE rank=1
ORDER BY Year
```

So what is happening here: Before applying RANK() OVER(), I'm getting rid of many of the combinations that won't matter when I'm looking for the top ones (as I'm filtering out everything with a count less than 100).

To give a more specific answer, it's always better if you can supply a query and sample data to review.

Comment: Thank you Fh. 
My problem is with Lead and Lag functions. I am trying to match sequences of event (Start Flow, End Flow) and than to analyze them (average duration (from start to end), median duration, etc.) 
I have ~1,000,000 such events. 
your suggested solution works great for ranking (where the window function can run on a smaller portion of the data). but for lead\ lag where I need entire data set, its problematic.
Unfortunately I cannot share my real data, and I cannot find similar scenario (volume ways) on public data besides the example i referred in the original question.

Comment: Note: This answer is out of date. PARTITION BY in the OVER clause is now executed in distributed fashion, like JOIN EACH or GROUP EACH BY.

Comment: Edited the Original question with a sample that still does not work :(