# Group by to get distinct rows in Google BigQuery takes much longer

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm doing a funnel analysis for the publicdata:samples.github_timeline dataset in Google BigQuery. I want to extract all unique users who did a series of three events, in chronological order.

The events and their order:

- WatchEvent
- PushEvent
- CreateEvent

This is the query:

```
    select user from (
    SELECT user1 as user,
        ts1 as eventDate1,
        ts2 as eventDate2,
        IF(ts2 < ts3, ts3, NULL) as eventDate3
     FROM
        (SELECT user1,
        ts1,
            ts2,
            ts3
            FROM (SELECT user1,
    ts1,
    IF(ts1 < ts2, ts2, NULL) as ts2
    FROM
    (SELECT user1,
    ts1,
    ts2
    FROM (SELECT repository_owner as user1,
    created_at as ts1
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
    WHERE type = "WatchEvent") as step1
    LEFT JOIN EACH (SELECT repository_owner as user2,
    created_at as ts2
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
    WHERE type = "PushEvent") as step2
    ON user1 = user2 where ts1 is not NULL)

    ) as steps1_2
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT repository_owner as user3,
            created_at as ts3
     FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
     WHERE type = "CreateEvent") as step3
           ON user1 = user3 
           where ts2 is not NULL
           )
    )
    where eventDate3 is not null
    group by user
    limit 100
```

Without the GROUP BY user at the end it's pretty fast (10 seconds). But when I add it, it takes a lot to complete (over 20 minutes).

What's wrong with the query?
You can test the query here: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/

Answer (score 3):

You've got a join explosion; that is, if user A has 20 WatchEvents, 20 PushEvents, and 20 CreateEvents, your query can generate 8000 rows out of these 60. This is because when there are multiple matching keys on both sides of the JOIN, it generates the cartesian product of the two sides. You can fix this by just taking the minimum matching time, so you're only looking at the min WatchEvent time for a user to find a subsequent PushEvent time, then looking at the minimum pushEvent time that is later than a WatchEvent time to find a matching CreateEvent time.

Here is a query that runs in about 20 seconds:

```
SELECT user 
FROM (
  SELECT step2_2.user1 as user,
    MIN(step2_2.ts1) as eventDate1,
    MIN(step2_2.ts2) as eventDate2,
    MIN(step3.ts3) as eventDate3
  FROM (
   SELECT user1, MIN(ts1) as ts1, MIN(ts2) as ts2
   FROM (
    SELECT repository_owner as user1,
    MIN(created_at) as ts1
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
    WHERE type = "WatchEvent"
    GROUP EACH BY user1) as step1
   JOIN EACH (
    SELECT repository_owner as user2,
      created_at as ts2
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
    WHERE type = "PushEvent") as step2
   ON user1 = user2
   WHERE ts1 < ts2
   GROUP EACH BY user1
  ) as step2_2
  JOIN EACH (
    SELECT repository_owner as user3,
      created_at as ts3
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
    WHERE type = "CreateEvent") as step3
  ON user1 = user3 
  WHERE step2_2.ts2 < step3.ts3
  GROUP EACH BY user
  ) 
GROUP BY user  
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data set is not too big  you can use the lead() window function to find the sequence and avoid joins altogether.

```
Select repository_owner 
FROM
(
Select repository_owner,type as Event0, 
LEAD(x,1) OVER(Partition by repository_owner order by ts) as Event1, 
LEAD(x,2) OVER(Partition by repository_owner order by ts) as Event2, 

FROM
(
SELECT repository_owner as user,created_at as ts,type as x
from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
where type in ("WatchEvent","PushEvent","CreateEvent")
))
where Event0="WatchEvent"
and Event1="PushEvent"
and Event2="CreateEvent"

Group by repository_owner
```

7 sec...

If events are not in "back to back order" (referring to Jordan's comment), need to make it a bit more complex:

```
    Select repository_owner from
(
Select repository_owner,Event0,Event1,
Lead(Event0,1) OVER (Partition by repository_owner order by ts) as Event2,
Lead(Event1,1) OVER (Partition by repository_owner order by ts) as Event3,
FROM
(Select * from
(Select repository_owner,type as Event0,ts, 
LEAD(x,1) OVER(Partition by repository_owner order by ts) as Event1, 
FROM
(
SELECT repository_owner as user,created_at as ts,type as x
from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
where type in ("WatchEvent","PushEvent","CreateEvent")
))
where (Event0="WatchEvent" and
     Event1 in("PushEvent" ,"CreateEvent"))
OR ( Event1="CreateEvent" and
   Event0 in("PushEvent" ,"WatchEvent")))
)
   Where Event0="WatchEvent" and 
      (Event1="PushEvent" Or Event2="PushEvent") and
      Event3="CreateEvent"
Group by repository_owner
```

If your dataset is too big then you hit this problem: [Parallelizable OVER EACH BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262753/parallelizable-over-each-by)

hope it helps

Comment: I think that this solution is more elegant than the one that I suggested, but does this only work if these events in this order back-to-back? For example, if there is a WatchEvent / PushEvent / WatchEvent / CreateEvent, won't this fail to match?

Comment: Edited my answer, added a solution for the scenario you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "limit 100" in non-grouping query, orchestrator will break execution after fetching first 100 data rows.

"group by user limit 100" demands that all data rows must be calculated before grouping. Then executes grouping. And in last after all "limit 100" goes in effect.

Comment: I've tried without the limit 100 and it took 23minutes.